# std::bad_weak_ptr exception in shared_from_this after object construction

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

I have a class defined similar to the following:

```
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public: 
  static std::shared_ptr<A> create() {
    return std::shared_ptr<A>(new A());
  }

  void f() { 
    shared_from_this();
  }

private:
  A() { }
};
```

and it's used similarly to:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> pt = A::create();
pt->f();
```

Despite the call to shared_from_this() being called after the shared_ptr `pt` is created, the call to `f()` still results in a `bad_weak_ptr` exception being thrown. Running it in `gdb` confirms that the exception is thrown on the call to `f()` and not in some code I haven't included here that's called by the instructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::enable_shared_from_this<A>` must be a *public* base. When the `shared_ptr` constructor sees that you've derived from `enable_shared_from_this`, it stores a weak copy of itself inside the `enable_shared_from_this` object. If the inheritance is not public, this cannot occur, and the `weak_ptr` stored inside the `enable_shared_from_this` will be null, leading to the `bad_weak_ptr` exception when `shared_from_this` later tries to construct a `shared_ptr` from it.

Comment: The example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) tends to suggest that the inheritance that OP is performing is correct.  It looks like the problem in the try-catch statement there.

Comment: @RobertPrévost — the inheritance in that example is public; `Good` is a `struct`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, good point.  It does say that on reexamining the example.

Answer (score 1):

Public inheritance is required here. As it is class A , hence it is not default. So is the reason for seeing the exception/ bad_weak_ptr.